# Pronuncia sce sci (e ce e ci?)

Tags: pronunciation, sound

Salve a tutti.
Vorrei chiedervi se secondo voi è corretto dire ai miei alunni che SC ha il suono duro se seguito da A O U (scale, bosco, scuro) ma "soft" se seguito da E e da I (scendere, scivolare, pesci etc..).

E anche:
questa regola c'entra niente con le pronunce di CI e CE?
Cinema (non *sinema* come mi dicono gli inglesi), 
cena,
ma: casa e cosa? Cinema e cena "soft", casa e cosa "hard"?

HELP! :)
zenkiuverymaaach!

Comment: La domanda non mi è molto chiara. Stai chiedendo se i termini "hard" e "soft" sono accettabili in inglese per le due pronunce italiane dei grafemi /sc/ e /c/?

Comment: Anche a me non è molto chiaro: ti interessano i termini in inglese o in italiano? Comunque stai parlando di tre fonemi diversi: /ʃ/ (“scena”), /tʃ/ (“cena”) e /k/ (“casa”).

Comment: Puoi trovare qui i nomi scientifici di questi tre suoni: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricativa_postalveolare_sorda , https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affricata_postalveolare_sorda , https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occlusiva_velare_sorda .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following ***[extract](http://www.italianlanguageguide.com/pronunciation/consonants/special-clusters.asp)*** may help:

Special clusters:  ***SC, SCA, SCO, SCU, SCE, SCI, SCIA, SCIE, SCIO, SCIU***:

> - ***The cluster sc only has a special sound when followed by vowels e and i***, in which case it sounds like an English sh in sharp, shelf, cash, shop.
>
>   - *Scena  »  scene /
>       Scesa  »  descent /
>       Scimmia  »  monkey /
>       Conoscere  »  to know /
>       Crescere  »  to grow /
>       Pesce  »  fish /
>       Scena  »  scene /*
> - ***In any other case (sca, sco, scu)*** the pronunciation is like the English one in scar scorpion, scub, scootera.
>
>   - *Scala  »  scale / 
>       Sconto  »  discount /
>       Scuola  »  school /
>       Ascoltare  »  to listen /
>       Pesca  »  peach /
>       Scaloppine  »  cutlets
>       Scarpa  »  shoe /*
> - ***When the cluster sci is followed by a vowel (scia, scie, scio, sciu), the sound of i is lost***; thus scia sounds like English sha, scie is pronounced she, scio as sho, and sciu as shu.
>
>   - *Fascia  »  diaper /  Sceicco  »  sheik /
>       Scialle  »  Scarf /
>       Sciroppo  »  Syrup /
>       Sciare  »  Sky*

***CE, CI, CIA, CIE, CIO, CIU***:

> - ***While ca, co and cu are pronounced as in English, ce and ci have a soft sound (palatal pronunciation)***, like in English che and chi.
> - ***When the cluster ci is followed by a further vowel, the i loses its sound, and becomes merely graphic (only to show that c has to be pronounced as English "ch")***. Therefore, cia sounds like cha (not chya), cie is pronounced che, cio as cho, and ciu as chu.
>
>   - *Cibo  »  food /
>       Certo  »  Certainly /
>       Ciao  »  Hello, goodbye /
>       Cioccolata  »  Chocolate /
>       Ciuccio  »  Baby’s pacifier*

www.italianlanguageguide.com

Answer (score 4):

Le varie lingue romanze hanno scelto modi diversi per indicare la palatalizzazione, ma c'è anche da tener conto di come la pronuncia derivata dal latino si sia modificata.

Consideriamo per esempio la parola latina *scientia*. In pronuncia classica sarebbe (approssimativamente, adoperando la grafia italiana moderna) *schientia*; la parola si è evoluta diversamente:

- italiano: scienza
- francese: science
- castigliano: ciencia
- catalano: ciència
- portoghese: ciência
- romeno: știință

L'esito di *sci* in latino diventa in italiano il suono palatale, nelle altre lingue l'esito è diverso. Per uniformità ortografica, la *s* è caduta in molte lingue. In francese, più restio a razionalizzare l'ortografia e propenso a preservare il riferimento etimologico, è rimasta anche se muta.

Ci sono varie ragioni per le quali lo stesso fonema /ʃ/ (quello che l'italiano usa per *scienza*) viene reso diversamente nelle altre lingue romanze che ce l'hanno:

- italiano: *sce* o *sci* (nel secondo caso la *i* può avere ruolo solo grafico) — *scena* *scimmia* *sciocco*
- francese: *ch* (che però in alcune parole ha il suono di *c*, per motivi etimologici) — *chemin* *chic*
- catalano: *ix* — *baixa*
- romeno: *ș* — *și*

In portoghese la *s* finale viene palatalizzata, ma non c'è un modo per indicare il fonema. Perché queste differenze? Proprio perché il fonema è l'esito di diversi fonemi latini, con ovvia influenza del substrato linguistico locale.

Per un'introduzione alla fonologia dell'italiano in quanto derivata dal latino, si veda un'[interessante voce dell'enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/fonologia_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/).

I termini *hard* e *soft*, pur se imprecisi, possono rendere l'idea. In italiano, *sce* e *sci* sono sempre pronunciati *soft*, cioè con il suono palatale. Nel caso di *sciocco* la *i* ha solo ruolo grafico e non va pronunciata; nel caso di *sciare* invece c'è chi la pronuncia (fra i quali io) e chi no: ortograficamente la *i* avrebbe solo ruolo grafico, come in *scialo*, ma etimologicamente la *i* c'è.

Se invece abbiamo *sca*, *sco* o *scu*, le due consonanti vanno pronunciate "separatamente".

Il discorso è simile per la *c*; il suono palatale (soft) si indica in italiano con *ce* o *ci* (di nuovo, la *i* potrebbe avere solo ruolo grafico)

- cena
- circo
- ciao (ruolo grafico)
- cieco (la *i* si pronuncia, ma l'intensità varia da regione a regione, vedi oltre)

Per indicare il suono non palatale (hard) in presenza di *e* o *i*, l'italiano adopera *ch*

- che
- china

La pronuncia è sempre *hard* davanti a *a*, *o* e *u*: *cane*, *cono*, *cubo*.

Si veda https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortografia_della_lingua_italiana per le regole principali dell'ortografia italiana.

La parola *china*, in una sua accezione, ha un'origine curiosa: *[inchiostro di china](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/china3)* sarebbe *di Cina*, ma siccome la locuzione è stata importata dal portoghese, la pronuncia ha seguito le regole generali dell'italiano scritto.

---

L'affermazione che la *i* in *cieco* si pronuncia forse farà sobbalzare qualcuno; ma chiunque abbia sentito pronunciare la parola da un napoletano non può avere dubbi. La grafia ha la *i* perché si tratta di un caso di “dittongo mobile”: si noti che in *cieco* la prima sillaba è tonica, mentre in *cecità* la sillaba in questione non è tonica. Il caso non è affatto diverso da *nuovo* e *novità*, oppure *lieto* e *letizia*. Il problema è solo che in *cieco* è presente il fonema /tʃ/ che in molte parlate regionali, in particolare settentrionali, fa sparire la *i* del dittongo. Aprire una discussione sul dittongo mobile qui è fuori luogo, si può vedere l'interessante [tesi di Bart van der Veer](https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/handle/1887/3773)

Comment: Ottima risposta, complimenti. Solo, metterei in evidenza che, fatte salve le variazioni regionali, la pronuncia “standard” di “sciare” è /ʃiˈare/ (cioè trisillaba, così come “scio” è bisillaba), mentre in “cieco” la “i” è puramente grafica e la pronuncia “standard” è /ˈtʃɛko/, omofono di “ceco” (abitante della Repubblica Ceca).

Comment: @DaG Dillo ai napoletani! Fra l'altro, la *i* c'è per motivi ben precisi (questioni di dittongo mobile, ma sarebbe molto lungo discuterne).

Comment: È possibile aggiungere, per completezza, uno o più link a cui poter fare riferimento?

Comment: @xxxxxx una qualsiasi grammatica?

Comment: Non so, è parte della policy del sito fornire  i link a supporto di quanto viene esposto. Era solo un suggerimento.

Comment: Il dittongo mobile è sacrosanto, ma non toglie che pronunciare la “i” in “cieco” è tipico solamente di alcune parlate regionali, così come non pronunciarla in “sciare”.

Comment: @DaG E non è quello che ho detto? Varia intensità va da zero a molto.

Comment: Grazie,  quello che cercavo è proprio qui : "La pronuncia è sempre hard davanti a A, O e U: cane, cono, cubo." Come è possibile secondo me dire che è hard la pronuncia di SCALE, SCUOLA, BOSCO (al contrario di SC con E e I (pesci, pesce). Grazie a tutti dei commenti, Fiona.